# TYPO3: Override $GLOBALS['TCA'] with a function

Tags: php, typo3, config

In my extension I use an tablename.php file inside the tca/override folder to override some stuff defined by another extension. I know I can do this:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tablename']['columns']['anoption']['config']['minitems'] = 1;
```

But when the original file says:

```
... 'anoption''config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
        'anoption',
        ['maxitems' => 7,]
```

What will be the override syntax? I was trying something like:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tablename']['columns']['anoption']['config']['anoption']['maxitems'] = 3;
```

But that doesn't work and I don't know what I have to insert after config since in the original file there is that getFileTCAConfig function.

Also I was wondering how I could debug "$GLOBALS['TCA']['tablename']['columns']['anoption']" to somehow see all the suboptions, since I did not find anything inside the mysql database, I couldn't read any config from the phpMyAdmin.

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct original code? It looks very broken and does not make sense. The first argument to `getFileFieldTCAConfig()` is always the field name it was called for, so in this case it must be `anoption` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can debug the final TCA in the TYPO3 backend through the **Configuration** module in the *System* section. Once you open that module you select **$GLOBALS['TCA'] (Table configuration array)** in the topmost function select box:

[image]

Comment: Found out about that just now, don't know why I haven't known that before :P With that I was able to solve my problem