# TYPO3 - TCA Migrations - Informational or ToDo?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I'm a newbie in `typo3`. A friend of me asked, if I can upgrade his installation for him, because I'm a developer. So I checked if I can do it.
I did several steps to upgrade the installation from `7.6.9` to `8.7.3`. Now I ended in the installation tool in the section `important actions`. There is a point `TCA migrations`.

There it says:

> TCA migrations need to be applied Check the following list and apply
>   needed changes.
>
> The icon path of wizard "link" from TCA table
>   "tx_myredirects_domain_model_redirect['columns']['destination']['config']['wizards']['link']['icon']"has
>   been migrated to
>   tx_myredirects_domain_model_redirect['columns']['destination']['config']['wizards']['link']['icon']"
>   = 'actions-wizard-link'. ...

[image]

Is this just informational or do I have to modify something in the things listed?

Sorry again, if this is a newbie question, but I am actually a newbie in `typo3`.

Comment: Additional information: As a general rule, you should refer to the TYPO3 changelog for deprecations and breaking changes for your release: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the extensions that need to migrate the TCAs haven't been created by you, then no, you do not really need to change them. The author of the extension should do it, because if you change them and then the author releases an update, then all your changes will be lost.

If the extension is a custom extension, then it would be better to migrate them. Then you can avoid bugs and unwanted disfunctions.

If you have a sitepackage, you can override the TCA's and give them new definitions. This way, if the author releases an update, your TCAs won't be lost. In order to do that, you can follow these instructions:

[Extending TCAs](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/Index.html)

An example would be:

**your_sitepackage/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_tablename_domain_model_modelname**

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_tablename_domain_model_modelname']['columns']['columnYouNeedToChange'] = [

'label' => 'input_29 link',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'input',
        'wizards' => [
            'link' => [
            'type' => 'popup',
            'title' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:header_link_formlabel',
            'icon' => 'actions-wizard-link',
            'module' => [
               'name' => 'wizard_link',
            ],
            'JSopenParams' => 'height=800,width=600,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1',
            'params' => [
                'blindLinkOptions' => 'folder',
                'blindLinkFields' => 'class, target',
                'allowedExtensions' => 'jpg',
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

This for example would solve the first problem of the image you shared. You just need to replace the table name. (That's TYPO3v8. TYPO3 v9 has more changes when it comes to TCAs)

If you are not sure how the path to the column look like (`$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_tablename_domain_model_modelname']['columns']['columnYouNeedToChange']`) then follow this:

[TCA Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50735695/typo3-override-globalstca-with-a-function)

@Thomas Löffler is right. It would be very useful to create an issue on GitHub and let the author know that some changes need to be made.

Best regards

Comment: If the extension is not created by you and not custom (third party extension), it would be helpful to create an issue for the extension owner to migrate this.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your help! I already saw now, that there were updates on the extensions. Then the list gets smaller and smaller. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This will show which TCA fields have been identified to have a legacy format and have been transformed while loading the configuration files.

While it is good practice to do these changes and keep this clean, strictly speaking it is not required.

Tip: I would rather look there before an upgrade because deprecated stuff might still have an upgrade path in an older version but none in the newest.